# Can I use « is » to compare against static variables?

Tags: python, enums, comparison, identity, static-variables

Python's [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) about the [`enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) says that enumerators [should be compared with `is`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/#comparisons) instead of the usual `==`. I guess that the reasoning is that an enum members are static and won't ever change, so it makes sense.

I am using Python 2.7.9 for compatibility reasons and I don't want to introduce too many new libraries to the project, so I don't plan to use the Python 2.7.9 port of the `enum` module. Therefore I use a simpler form of enumerations instead:

```
class Color(object):
    red = 1
    green = 2
    blue = 3
```

In such a case, is it still fine to use `is` for comparison? More generally, is it ok to compare static class variables that are known not to change during the lifetime of the program with `is` instead of `==`, regardless of their type?

**Note:** I take that only the name of the static variable will be used for assignment/comparison, never its value.

Comment: What advantage do you gain from comparing these things with `is`? Your code will look like it is wrong even if it works.

Comment: @khelwood Documentation. If it works, then reading `is` in my code will clearly trigger `static` or `enum` in my mind.

Comment: If you _only ever_ compare class attributes then `is` is fine. Eg, `a=Color.red;b=Color.red;c=Color.blue;print a is b, a is c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you? **Yes** - small integers are interned in CPython, so wherever you get e.g. `x = 2` from, `x is Color.green` will evaluate `True`.

Should you? **No**. For one thing, it doesn't make conceptual sense - do you really care if they're the same exact object (*identity*, `is`), or just whether they have the same value (*equality*, `==`)? What if the values are sourced from somewhere other than the class itself, e.g. a database or user input? For another, interning of small integers is an *implementation detail*, so shouldn't be relied upon.

> More generally, is it ok to compare static class variables that are known not to change during the lifetime of the program with `is` instead of `==`, regardless of their type?

**No**, because this could fail whether or not they are *"static"*:

```
>>> class Demo(object):
    class_attr = "some string"


>>> "some string" is Demo.class_attr
False
```

Comment: Your final example is not one of my use cases. I would only write `a = Demo.class_attr` at some point and check `a is class_attr` at some other point. I wouldn't really care about the value actually.

Comment: Again, what if the value comes from somewhere else? If you're **always** going to have the same object then it's up to you, but I don't think it's the best approach.

Comment: That's good point. I wonder how Python 3.4 enums behave if you try to load their values from somewhere else.

Comment: @Morwenn you have to call the class to get the member - see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes).

Comment: @Morwenn I would argue that you can't guarantee that you will __always__ have the same object on both end hence it's quite pointless to risk creating hard to diagnose problems just to use __is__ (e.g. 5 is 5 but 300 is not 300)

Comment: @user3012759 But I can guarantee for `a = 300; b = a`, then `a is b` is always `True` provided `a` never changes, right?

Comment: @Morwenn yes, because `a` and `b` are both references to the same object; as long as neither `a` nor `b` is reassigned, `a is b`.

Comment: @Morwenn yes, this case will work but can you guarantee that the ones that come after you will not violate this rule?

Comment: @user3012759 More or less. Since I generally don't remember the values of enumerators and therefore only ever use their names...

Answer (score 1):

It **may** work since CPython uses the same addresses for the numbers in `[-5, ..., 256]` (they are never re-created):

```
>>> (-5 + 0) is -5
True
>>> (-6 + 0) is -6
False
>>> (256 + 0) is 256
True
>>> (257 + 0) is 257
False
```

But it's relying on implementation which is not a good thing.

Why not use `==` anyway?